# How can I get sum of column values in Qtable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I use Quasar framework

I have a table with calories column, and I change the value of calories and I want to get sum of all calories and I use `sumOfCalories` computed , but It doesn't work after I change the value of calories

```
  const sumOfCalories = computed(() => {
    return rows[0]['calories'] + rows[1]['calories'];
  })
```

For test I use rows 0 and 1 with index but I need total of all rows

codepen: https://codepen.io/mohammad6006/pen/JjwZYqJ

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your rows in a ref like this

```
 const rows = ref([
  {
    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
    calories: 159,
    fat: 6.0,
    carbs: 24,
    protein: 4.0,
    sodium: 87,
    calcium: '14%',
    iron: '1%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
    calories: 237,
    fat: 9.0,
    carbs: 37,
    protein: 4.3,
    sodium: 129,
    calcium: '8%',
    iron: '1%'
  }
])
```

and then you can change your computed to something like this

```
const sumOfCalories = computed(() => {
        let sum = 0;
        for(const row of rows.value){
          sum += +row['calories']
        }
        return sum;
      })
```

Comment: Alternative https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/poqKyPa